# Solve the following in-equation

Tags: inequality

> $$1 \le |x-2| \le 3$$

If we solve it separately 
$$1\le |x-2|$$
$x-2\ge 1$ and $x-2\le -1$

So $x\in (-\infty , -3]\cup [1, \infty)$

For the second part 
$$|x-2|\le 3$$
So $x-2\le 3$ and $x-2\ge -3$

Here $x\in [-1,5]$

Now if I take their intersection , the final answer will (or should be, according to me) [-1,5]. Yet the right answer is $x\in [-1,1]\cup[3,5]$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your intersection is not correct. Note that your first result does not include a neighborhood of the origin.

Comment: If e.g. $x=2$ then $|x-2|=0\notin[1,3]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a mistake:
$x-2 \geq 1 \iff x \geq 3 $, and
$x-2 \leq -1\iff x\leq 1$.

So you get $x \in [-\infty,1] \cup [3, \infty]$.  And then you get the right answer by intersecting with your second part.

Answer (score 1):

For $$x\geq 2$$ we get
$$1\le x-2\le 3$$ so
$$3\le x\le 5$$
If $x<2$ then we get
$$1\le -x+2\le 3$$ so
$-1\le -x\le 1$ so$$-1\le x\le 1$$

Answer (score 1):

Squaring gives the equivalent system $$1\le(x-2)^2\le 9.$$ Solving the first gives $(x-2)^2-1\ge 0,$ or $(x-3)(x-1)\ge 0.$ The second gives $(x-2)^2-3^2\le 0,$ or $(x-5)(x+1)\le 0.$

The first thus implies $x\in(-\infty,1]\cup[3,+\infty)$ and the second that $x\in [-1,5].$ The intersection of these sets is $[-1,1]\cup[3,5].$